# How do I detect tab was touched in xamarin forms TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin.forms

How could I detect tab was touched in xamarin forms TabbedPage?
(which is different from page changed detection which I figured how to detect)

Here is why:
I'm trying to work around a rather ugly tabbed page overflow UI
(the ugly scroller that shows up on the right over the tabbar
whenever there are >5 tabs)
So the 5th tab press shows a custom menu, second press hides that menu, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: same problem. can you give your answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are trying to find which page is selected in TabbedPage  you could do it in this way.
   With Index value you can perform whatever action you want..

**Event for detecting page no:**

```
    this.CurrentPageChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            var i = this.Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Page No:"+i);
        };
```

Comment: as I stated in my question when you sit on page X a second tap on the very same tab will NOT be delivered as a page changed event. Cause, technically, the page did not change.

Comment: I guess I'll accept it given that my finding is not an issue for 6 people and i no longer use xamarin to see if this was fixed in the latest installment...

Comment: Sigh... Did anyone ever find a way to do this that would also catch if you tap on the same page you are currently on?

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since this was asked but just in case here is an answer.

Perform an action when a tab is tapped is the same as when:

- The tab has changed
- The tab is "reselected"

So for the first one you can use @femil-shajin 's answer or as I do here which is more direct and for the second one you need to make some custom renderers for the `TabbedPage`:

```cs
public class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
    ...

    protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
    {
         // do whatever
    }    
    
    public void OnTabReselected()
    {
         // do whatever
    }

    ...
}
```

Then on Android:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomTabbedRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer, NavigationBarView.IOnItemReselectedListener
    {
        ...
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                GetBottomNavigationView()?.SetOnItemReselectedListener(this);
            }
        }

        private BottomNavigationView GetBottomNavigationView()
        {
            // this may need to change on some cases 
            for (var i = 0; i < ViewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var childView = ViewGroup.GetChildAt(i);
                if (childView is ViewGroup viewGroup)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < viewGroup.ChildCount; j++)
                    {
                        var childRelativeLayoutView = viewGroup.GetChildAt(j);
                        if (childRelativeLayoutView is BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView)
                        {
                            return bottomNavigationView;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void OnNavigationItemReselected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            if (Element is MyTabbedPage tabbedPage)
            {
                tabbedPage.OnTabReselected();
            }
        } 
        ...
    }
}
```

And on iOS:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomTabbedRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        private UITabBarItem _previousSelectedItem;

        ...
        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

            if (SelectedIndex < TabBar.Items.Length)
            {
                _previousSelectedItem = TabBar.Items[SelectedIndex];
            }
        }

        public override void ItemSelected(UITabBar tabbar, UITabBarItem item)
        {
            if (_previousSelectedItem == item && Element is MyTabbedPage tabbedPage)
            {
                tabbedPage.OnTabReselected();
            }
            _previousSelectedItem = item;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Source: Part of this was based on [this page](https://criticalhittech.com/2017/09/14/tab-reselection-in-xamarin-forms-part-1/)